# Scrapy - XPath for Next Page

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I having real trouble getting the XPath for a "Next page" URL for a site.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="pagingcont">

        <div class="right margintop" id="save_search_header_popup" style="width:550px;">
            <div class="left marginleft" style="padding-top:1px;">
                <div class="left save_search_env"><img src="/themes/LW1/refresh/images/envelope_icon.gif" alt="Save" />&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="left">
                    Save this search and receive email alerts of new listings
                    &nbsp;<input type="text" maxlength="100" value="Name this search" onfocus="doSavedSearchFocus(this,'Name this search');" style="width:120px;height:14px;color:Gray;"/>&nbsp;
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left save_search_btn" style="margin-right:10px;"><img class="pointer" src="/themes/LW1/refresh/images/btn_save.gif" alt="Save"  onclick="showPopup(document.getElementById('save_search_header_popup'), null, 'In order to be notified of new or updated properties, you need to be registered and signed in.');return false;"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left margintop marginleft" style="cursor:pointer;height:27px;" onclick="javascript:docompare(true);">
            <div class="left"><img src="//www.landwatch.com/themes/LW1/images/comparebtn_btm.gif" style="margin-bottom:0px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="left active" style="margin-top:4px;">COMPARE</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear topline"></div>

    <div class="clear margin">
        <b>Page &nbsp;</b>
        &nbsp;<span class="active" style="padding:3px 3px 3px 4px;border:solid 1px black;">1&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=2">2</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=3">3</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=4">4</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=5">5</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=6">6</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=7">7</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=8">8</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=9">9</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=10">10</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=11">11</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=12">12</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=13">13</a>&nbsp;| <a href="https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2c&pg=2">Next</a>
    </div>
```

(The href I am looking for is the very bottom right, which is inconvenient to view here...)

My scrapy tries the following:

```
next_page_url = response.xpath("//div[@class='pagingcont']//span//a[text()='Next']/href")
    next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)

    for href in response.css('div.propName a::attr(href)'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product_page)
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

But each time, the scrapy gives me the first page of results and then nothing else.  So I don't think it's finding the next page effectively.  What's wrong about that next_page_url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath has two issues:

1. It's looking for a `<span>` that is not in your data
2. `href` is an attribute, not a node, so it should be `@href`.

Full working example below.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy import Request

class LandSpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.landwatch.com/default.aspx?ct=r&type=5,37;268,6843&=&px=2000000&r.PSIZ=500%2C&pg=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        next_page_url = response.xpath(
            "//div[@class='pagingcont']//a[text()='Next']/@href").extract_first()

        for href in response.css('div.propName a::attr(href)'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_product_page)
        yield Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_product_page(self, response):
        return response.xpath("//div[@class='detTitle']/text()").extract_first()
```

Results:

```
[
{"title": "Lulaton, Brantley County, Coast, GA Land For Sale - 936 Acres"},
{"title": "Oglethorpe County, GA Land For Sale - 515 Acres"},
{"title": "Dawsonville, Lumpkin County, GA Land For Sale - 525 Acres"},
{"title": "Wheeler County, GA Land For Sale - 594 Acres"},
{"title": "Cedartown, Polk County, GA Land For Sale - 1185.65 Acres"},
...
]
```

Comment: There we have it.  Thank you very, very much, jschnurr.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for the html example you are showing, there is no `span` as parent of an `a` tag, so doing `//span//a` is not getting anything. So maybe your xpath should only be:

```
"//div[@class='pagingcont']//a[text()='Next']/href"
```

Of course it could be better.

Now you are also not getting the value on your python code, which should be done with `.extract_first`, so your first `next_page_url` variable (your first line of the code shared) is a `Selector`, not actually a string. Change it to:

```
next_page_url = response.xpath("//div[@class='pagingcont']//a[text()='Next']/href").extract_first()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  Unfortunately, it still only goes through the first page.  Does not move to next page.